# Django: json.dumps breaks JSON arrays

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to display a JSON doc in a HTML form, broken into separate input items, allow modifications, then convert it back to a JSON doc.

Firstly I use `data = json.load(json_data)` to convert the doc to an object and then pass `data` to template, accessing its attributes in the template as so: `<input type="hidden" name="countries" value="{{ data.countries }}">`.

Once posted back to the view I'm using `doc = json.dumps(request.POST)` to serialize it back to JSON. This works fine for everything bar arrays: `"countries": "[u'US']"`, which should instead look like: `"countries": ['US']`

I could use string operations to clean it up, but is there a better way?

**view.py (stripped out the DB code)**

```
def addProducts(request):
    if request.POST:
        doc = json.dumps(request.POST)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/add_product')

    json_data = open('items.json')
    data = json.load(json_data)
    return render("add_products.html", {
        "products": data,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

`doc` ends up being a string:

```
{"doc_type": "Product", "countries": "[u'US']"}
```

original data in `items.json`:

```
 {"doc_type": "Product", "countries": ["US"]}
```

Comment: How's the POST being submitted?

Comment: in the template? via a form `<input type="submit" id="add" value="add">`

Comment: This looks like something that should not happen since QueryDict gets serialized in the same way as normal dict. Also judging from the form of this string (the `u` prefix) it looks that you are doing something weird along the lines like setting `request.POST["countries"]` to `str(arr)` instead of `arr`. Please post the full code.

Comment: @KingFu If that's the only relevant code, then it seems that you are receiving malformed data from the client. This might mean that `items.json` file is corrupted. Check it. Otherwise the "stripped out DB code" might be responsible (corrupted). If both are correct, then the error is on client side (I assume JavaScript).

Comment: @freakish that's the only relevant code, the DB stuff is after `doc` , im debugging it and breaking it on `doc` to inspect the data. I've checked `items.json` and the data looks fine: `"countries": ["US"],`

Comment: @KingFu Try placing `print request.POST["countries"]` at the begining and tell us what you see (be very precise, every `"` matters).

Comment: @freakish ok done, console shows: `[u'US']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allright. The culprit is this line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="countries" value="{{ data.countries }}">
```

In a way you are doing you are actually passing `str(data.countries)` to your template (implicitly) which produces these funky errors. You have to serialize it first and then in your view you have to parse it again:

```
def addProducts(request):
    if request.POST:
        post = {}
        for key in request.POST:
            value = request.POST[key]
            try:
                value = json.loads(value)
            except Exception:
                pass
            post[key] = value
        doc = json.dumps(post)
    # the other code goes here

    return render("add_products.html", {
        "products": data,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Now this looks like an overkill, but it has to be done, since `request.POST` is a dictionary of JSON strings (which you have to manually convert to dict/JSON).

**Conclusion:** having JSON values in forms might not be a good idea in the first place.

Comment: Couldn't get `value="{{ json.dumps(data.countries) }}` to work, so did it on the view side instead with `for d in data:    d['countries'] = json.dumps(d['countries'])` this combined with your view code produces `"countries": "[\"US\"]"`, which i'm not sure is correct JSON? The code changes also cause the doc to get repeated many times which I need to take a look at

Comment: @KingFu I've just realized: you do not have `"data"` in your `return render` statement. How is it passed to the template??

Comment: @KingFu As for the JSON: it is a valid JSON, however there was a mistake in my code. It should be `value = request.POST[key]` (the first line in the loop). And yes, your solution is how it should be. I forgot that you can't fire functions in Django templates (working for too long with Mako).

Comment: ah brilliant your last comment solved it! thank you so much. Had no idea it would turn into something so involved!! Out of interest would it of been better to convert the JSON doc to a django model first?